# Alien Swarm: is the armor useless?

Tags: alien-swarm

I was told in an online game not to use armor in Alien Swarm.  Is it really useless, and if not, when is it useful?

Comment: What class do you usually play?

Comment: @badp Just starting, trying to learn them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been playing as a medic; provided the armour does reduce damage by 20%, it's saved me (and my team) from death many times.

However, if you are playing as (say) a officier, you are going to have much more hitpoints to play with and armour becomes comparatively less useful. I'd still go with electric armour, though, because getting infested really is expensive (especially on the healgun).

It depends on your class, play style and ability to swiftly move from the wrong end of a shotgun to the wrong end of a flamethrower.

Answer (score 1):

As you start to progress to harder difficulties, you will ending a dedicated healer. These healing resources get depleted pretty quickly and you can only have one heal gun (unless you make someone else go healer and take one and swap when it runs out)

As a result, taking less damage is very important. It is preferred that your players are better at avoiding taking the damage of course, but if its still too much the armor never hurts.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if you're prone to taking large amounts of damage or not.

If you are, then the armor will save your medic's resources.

In short, if you take lots of damage then the armor is useful.  If you take very little damage, however, you were probably better off taking something else instead.

Answer (score 1):

The armor is absolutely useless, because it's taking up a slot that could be used to carry items that prevent you from taking damage at all.

- Freeze grenades (level 8) a great choice for neutralizing large
  swarms, or for when you or your teammates get swarmed.
- Hornet barrage (level 6) can also save your bacon if you get
  surrounded, though it's not as effective as freeze grenades.
- Electric armor (level 14) stuns nearby and attacking enemies, kills
  parasites on contact and heals infestation, a must on parasite-heavy
  maps.
- Officer mines are great for defending an area.

You will never see a skilled player rolling with heavy armor, do yourself and your team a favor and pick up some freeze grenades.